# Eloquent "with" returns null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm getting all courses with user (author of this course), but it returns me null.
After debuging i tried diferent way to get relation, but it gives me diferent result.

i'm confused because of `$course->user (null) | $course->user()->first() (expected result)`, but for some of users `$course->user` gives me expected result...

```
$coursesModel = Course::latest()->with(['user.profile', 'reviews:course_id'])->get();

    foreach ($coursesModel as $key => $course)
    {
        if (!$course->user)
            dd($course, $course->user, User::find($course->user_id), $course->user()->first());
    }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

User Model:

```
public function courses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
}
```

Couse Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

DataBase:

```
-users
  ->id
-courses
  ->id
  ->user_id
```

Comment: `$course->user` can return `null` for a number of reasons; the `user_id` (or however your link the two models) could be `null` or `0`, the `User` could be deleted (doesn't exist in the `users` table, or is "Soft Deleted", etc.). You'll probably have to show your `Course` and `User` models, the relationship and table structure. Sidenote, `$course->user;` and `$course->user()->first();` should return the same thing.

Comment: @TimLewis, that what i'm talking : ) strange thing here is `$course->user` and `$course->user()->first()` returns diferent result

Comment: It shouldn't... Do you have a `user` column on your `courses` table? (Edit: screenshot suggests you don't) Or some other method that overrides it?

Comment: @TimLewis yes, on 1st screenshot is a course table dump (here is `user_id`), plus update question.

Comment: Everything looks ok, and the fact that `$course->user()->first()` works suggests the relationship is constructed properly. You don't have a `getUserAttribute()` on your `Course.php` model, do you? That's the only thing I can think of that would return `null` for `$course->user`...

Comment: @TimLewis No, never heard about this method. null returns only for part of users...

Comment: That would be a custom method, so you'd know if you defined it :) Unfortunately I'm not sure then what's up then; everything looks ok, and I've never seen an instance where one approach works and the other doesn't...

Comment: @TimLewis For me too, that why i'm here : ) can its be because of i'm using `uuid` instead `id` ?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong spot. You've expanded the attributes of the `course`, but the `user` is in the `relations`. Accessing `course->user` is very different from `course->user()`. You've also asked for just `user.profile`, not `user` in your with().

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke `dd($course->user)` should still work, with or without the use of `with('user')`. It shouldn't return `null` if `$course->user()->first();` returns the User.

Comment: @DarrylE.Clarke also why some of courses returns me users with `$course->user` ?

Comment: @hitt, can you share the entire Course model code?

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/59a44bb98f58ec7ba37c0d0959d0e5fa95f06a40 please

Comment: @hitt, thanks. The code seems to be correct. Relations are defined and called properly. I would assume the issue could be outside of the code provided, like third-party packages that could alter how relations work or simply a bug. If that's possible I would suggest to create a repository with a reproducible bug, so we can clone it and inspect. I believe the issue is outside of the provided code and the results are definitely odd.

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev i can share composer.json here is no noname package inside of project